# How to call PostgreSQL function in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis

I have PostgreSQL+PostGIS.

I java i want to call this query:

```
SELECT num,id,mydata, asText(the_geom) FROM filedata
```

But get `NullPointerException`.
I think its couse i try to call function `asText` in this query and do it wrong. What i gonna do?

**UPDATE**

This is my code:

```
IndexedContainer container = createContainer("SELECT num,id,mydata, asText(the_geom) FROM filedata");

public IndexedContainer createContainer(String SQL) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection con= null;
      con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");


    IndexedContainer container = new IndexedContainer();
    String sSQL = SQL;

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sSQL);
 ////*****////
}
```

Comment: A `NullPointerException` is never ambiguous. Check the stacktrace (then step through the code if necessary) to see what's null. Then find out why.

Comment: show some more code. how do you exec the sql query?

Comment: You will need to show the relevant java code.

Comment: Maybe the java framework wants to see a name for the derived field. `SELECT num,id,mydata, astext(the_geom) AS text_geom FROM filedata`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your problem is in `the_geom` - it is **NOT** table column (unless you did not follow any naming standards). If you are trying to build SQL in Java and pass a value from Java variable to SQL than you can use query parameters.
I suspect that you "forgot" that your SQL actually runs on SQL server where Java variables are not available.